# TPU in colab fails while GPU works

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am working on a modified version of the [TPU fmnist example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/fashion_mnist.ipynb). While the original works fine, in my version I reduce the frequency of some classes according to a percentile (also omitting some classes, but that does not seem to cause the problem).

Training on TPU results in a very uninformative error regarding shape mismatch:

> Run-time shape mismatch for TPUExecute argument[0] (cond_15/Merge).
>   Expected element_type: F32

Running the exact same code on GPU works.

I assume it is due to workload sharing between the TPU's, but I am a bit lost on how to fix it.

I am attaching a link to the notebook, and the code below it. It is currently on TPU, to run on GPU uncomment the relevant startegy, while commenting the TPU parts, and change the colab runtime.

[colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15NmmnLVTcIgmg9kOtB47jEJOnLt4cE1X)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import distutils
if distutils.version.LooseVersion(tf.__version__) < '1.14':
    raise Exception('This notebook is compatible with TensorFlow 1.14 or higher, for TensorFlow 1.13 or lower please use the previous version at https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/r1.13/tools/colab/fashion_mnist.ipynb')

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
def make_tail_ds(x_train, y_train,x_test,y_test, tail_classes, omitted_classes, precentile):
    true_indices = np.invert(np.isin(y_train,tail_classes+omitted_classes))
    tail_indices = np.isin(y_train,tail_classes)
    normal_data = x_train[true_indices]
    normal_gt = y_train[true_indices]
    tail_data = x_train[tail_indices]
    tail_gt = y_train[tail_indices]
    tail_len = int(np.floor(len(tail_gt)*precentile))
    tail_data =tail_data[:tail_len]
    tail_gt =tail_gt[:tail_len]
    new_train = np.concatenate([normal_data,tail_data])
    new_gt = np.concatenate([normal_gt,tail_gt])
    test_indices = np.invert(np.isin(y_test,omitted_classes))
    return np.copy(new_train),np.copy(new_gt), np.copy(x_test[test_indices]),np.copy(y_test[test_indices])




x_train, y_train,x_test,y_test = make_tail_ds(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test, [3,4], [8,9],0.9)



# add empty color dimension
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)


def create_model(num_of_classes):
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('elu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_of_classes))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))
  return model

import os

resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver('grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

# strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device="/gpu:0")

with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model(len(np.unique(y_train)))
  model.compile(
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, ),
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(
    x_train.astype(np.float32), y_train.astype(np.float32),
    epochs=17,    
    validation_data=(x_test.astype(np.float32), y_test.astype(np.float32)), batch_size = 100

)

model.save_weights('./fashion_mnist.h5', overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, back to GPUs for now :/